# Intuit API Bypass Authorization Page/Login

Tags: mule, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am creating a **MuleSoft** application which uses Intuit API to create Bills in QuickBooks Desktop Application. Now the problem that i am facing is, that to connect to Intuit API, i need Access Token which requires a Authorization code to be generated. This happens when a user logs in to a URL and clicks on an Authorize button. I don't have a front end application/page which i can display to the user and ask the user to login and Authorize the application and the page that already exists cannot be changed because that is under control of Intuit.
How can i bypass this step and directly get the Authorization code to generate Token.

Answer (score 0):

> QuickBooks Desktop Application. Now the problem that i am facing is,
>   that to connect to Intuit API, i need Access Token which requires a
>   Authorization code to be generated.

QuickBooks desktop *does not require an access token*.

I think you're trying to connect to QuickBooks Online.

> I don't have a front end application/page which i can display to the
>   user and ask the user to login and Authorize the application

Why can't you implement a front-end application/page?

MuleSoft seems to support this for Salesforce, which uses the identical OAuth2 standard. Why can't you do similar?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-a-connector-to-access-an-oauth-api

Comment: Thanks, my API is creating Bills and Invoices for Desktop App only. After using your comment, i found out a Mulesoft connector for QuickBooks Windows but i am unable to use it and getting a Bad Request error. Can you please share an example of how to use it in case you have used it? How can i use it without the access_token?

Comment: QuickBooks for Windows DOES NOT HAVE access tokens. Access tokens are for QuickBooks Online only. I think you're looking at two separate things here and getting them confused.

Comment: yes i was confused, its QB desktop , do we have any connector in Anypoint studio for this? Will QuickBooks Winidows connector work for this?